# Python top level module

Tags: python

I'm going mad about creating a module in Python:

Say I'm calling it "my_module"

I've created a folder called "my_module", in which I've put "setup.py" and all the other files required for the installation and manteinance.

Then **inside** my_module folder I created another folder called, again, **my_module**, inside of which I put the *
**init**.py file and some other files like *foo.py*, *foo2.py*

What I really don't understand is why now I have to call

`from my_module.my_module.foo import ...`

instead of

`from my_module.foo import ...`

Does anybody know where am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Because you have 2 my_module folders? That seems expected to me.

Comment: well thing doesn change even if I call the top folder "my_top_folder", I will have to import my_top_folder.my_module.foo again... Shouldn't the module live inside within the folder where I created the __init__.py file?

Comment: Again, that seems like expected behavior.  my_module does not have a file called foo inside of it, it just has an additional folder called my_module inside of it.

Comment: Python searches for modules from `sys.path`.  Print that out and see which top level directory it will search from.  If `my_top_folder` is not there then it would need to be specified.

Comment: thanks @cdarke, this behavior was unfamiliar to me